# Setting default content permissions?

Tags: entities, users

I've got a Drupal site with a large amount of CCK fields already populated. I'd like to allow non registered users to be able to submit a particular content type, but I don't want all the fields to be available to them.

I can, obviously, use Content Permissions to do this, but I have 100+ fields that I would need to set individual permissions for, and would also need to set permissions every time I added a new field.

Is there a way I can set default permissions for all fields? So, for example, all fields are editable by admin and viewable by all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I'm being lazy here, so I just decided to bite the bullet and install the module. However, I have found a shortcut for Chrome users. Here's what I did:

1. Go to admin/user/permissions
2. Open up the Javascript console
3. Assuming your theme already loads jQuery (which it should if you've got the default theme, type $("input[id*=edit-3-edit-field-]").attr('checked','checked'); and press enter to check all the admin permissions boxes to edit
4. To allow unauthenticated users to view all fields type $("input[id*=edit-1-view-field-]").attr('checked','checked'); and press enter
5. Adjust as necessary for the permissions you want.
6. Click 'Save permissions'

I guess this would work for any other browser with a Javascript console too, but I've not tested it.

It doesn't get round the issue of having to add permissions for every single new field, but I guess it's just something I'll have to live with!

Answer (score 0):

I think, the module [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) can solve all of your problems.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that module, but it doesn't solve my immediate problem. What I'm after is a way to set sensible defaults for each field, which I can override if needs be, rather than having to set permissions for 100+ fields and having to remember to set permissions each time I set a new field up.